# CI/CD with GitHub and Plesk

Tags: deployment, github-actions

We succesfully use the Plesk / Github integration that deploys our developers pushes from github to our plesk stage web server using the Webhooks to have Plesk get the latest version. That works splendidly.

What we try to establish additionally is auto compile the SCSS source and submit the resulting css to our stage web server. We have added an action to the workflow but how would the compiled products end up on our stage webserver. I'm unsure if the timing in the complete workflow is right. Will the actions be performed before deployment?

This is the yaml:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - stage


jobs:
  build_css:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source Git branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            ref: stage
            fetch-depth: 10
            submodules: true
      - name: Make destination directory for compiled CSS
        run: mkdir -vp /tmp/theme/assets/
        
      - name: Compile CSS from SCSS files
        uses: gha-utilities/sass-build@v0.4.11
        with:
          source: assets/src/main.scss
          destination: /tmp/theme/assets/

      - name: Move compiled CSS to path within stage branch
        run: mv /tmp/theme/assets assets/
```